# SSH setup issues

Tags: bash, ssh, git-bash

I am trying to use ssh however when I try and set it up by typing

```
ssh - host - config
```

I get the errot "ssh: Could not resolve hostname -: Name or service not known"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is  either in server name or in the way you call it!

```
ssh user@server
```